# problema realizar reserva php

Tags: php, mysql, html5

quería pedir de su ayuda nuevamente, si esta la disponibilidad de ayudarme con esto , a un me cuesta llevar la teoría a la practica

paso 2

En la carpeta “models” debes crear la clase para realizar la conexión a la
base de datos, y la entidad relacionada con la tabla “reservas”. Sólo se
necesita crear reservas.

esto tengo en este paso, me falta ingresar la entidad para realizar solo reservas , no se como implementarlo

```
   <?php

   class Conexion {

   function conectarBD(){
      $server = "localhost";
      $usuario = "root";
      $contraseña = "";
      $baseDeDatos = "bdreservoir";

      $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $baseDeDatos) or die ("Error al 
      conectar con la base de datos");

      if($conexion){
       echo "Conexion exitosa";
      }
     }
    }
   ?>
```

Paso 3
En la carpeta “controllers” debes crear el controlador relacionado con la
entidad reserva

- aqui no entiendo  que se refiere , la vdd el materia de estudio que nos entrega es nada, he buscado por internet , solo he encontrado cosas hechas

Paso 4
En la carpeta “views” debes crear la página que contenga al formulario de
ingreso de reservas

```
     <?phpinclude ("sections/header.php");?>
     <h1> HAZ TU RESERVA </h1>

    <form >
    Rut: <input type="texto" name="rut"><br/><br/>
    Nombre: <input type="texto" name="nombre"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="btnRegistrar">
    </form>

    <?php include ("sections/footer.php")?>
```

- igual ahora teniendo todos los pasos , como debo hacer que la conexión de bd sea parte de los otros archivos php?
- al aplicar estilo css no me toma en el reservas.php, en la carpeta views/css ( tengo el estilo.css), tengo el link en el archivo header.php que esta en la carpeta sections.
  link lo tengo asi

  esto serian los otros pasos que ya los tengo realizados

  Crear tabla con el nombre “reservas” con las siguientes columnas
  Id: Numerico, debe autoincrementarse
  Rut: Texto, almacena el rut del cliente
  Nombre: Texto, almacena el nombre y apellido del cliente
  FechaHora: Almacena la fecha y hora de registro de la reserva

  ```
  Paso 2
  Crear una carpeta para el proyecto con el nombre “reservoir”. En esta, crear
  la subcarpertas “models”, “views”, “controllers”. Dentro de la carpeta “views”
  debes crear las carpetas “css”, “img”, “js” y “sections”. En “sections” debes
  crear los archivos que representan la cabecera y pie de una página HTML.
   Dentro de la carpeta raíz del proyecto debes crear un archivo php llamado
  “index” que redirija al formulario de ingreso de reservas
  ```

agradecería de su apoyo, php y poo a un me cuesta aplicarlo , ojala que puedan ayudarme , saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de comenzar, debes leer acerca de MVC, Modelo Vista Controlador, el cual es un patrón de arquitectura de software, que permite tener un código mas legible y ordenado. La estructura de esta arquitectura consta de esta manera:

```
Reserva
  ->Models
    ->User.php
    ->Post.php
  ->Views
    ->index.view.php
    ->form.index.php
  ->Controllers
    ->CrudeController.php
  ->Database
    ->mibd.sql
```

En donde podemos identificar que, las 3 carpetas principales son:

- Modelo (donde se guarda todo lo relacionado al objeto que se desea mapear, en tu caso, reservaciones)
- Vista: En donde se guardan todas las paginas que el usuario ve a la hora de interactúa con tu sistema, normalmente llevan los nombres de la acción y `.view.php`, tipo `crear.view.php`
- Controlador: aquí ira toda la lógica de tu programa, es decir, debes instanciar una conexión a la BD, también los métodos que tendra tu programa, los cuales son CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete), además se debe agregar con `require 'index.view.'` los archivos de la vista.

Comprendiendo esto, te echo la mano en como debes estructurar todo y que debe ir en cada uno

Bien vamos por partes:

- Paso 1: La conexión a la base de datos

Veo que ya tienes una conexión a la base de datos, sin embargo podemos mejorar algunas cosas para que funcione mejor y se adapte a lo que pide el maestro: que uses MVC (Modelo-Vista-Controlador)

Primero, definimos algunas constantes para la conexión, estos estarán en un archivo llamado `Config.php` (o agregarle el nombre que quieras).

```
<?php 
//Definiendo constantes para la conexion a la bd
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
  define('DB_NAME', 'dbreservoir');
  define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
?>
```

Una vez que ya tengas esto, vamos al archivo de la conexión y hacemos unos pequeños ajustes para trabajar con el MVC

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

class Connect {
  protected $connection;
  

  public function __construct(){
    $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($this->connection->connect_errno) {
      echo "Error al conectarte a la BD {$this->connection->connect_errno}";

      return;
    }
    $this->connection->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);
  }
}
?>
```

- Paso 2: Nos dice que debes crear una carpeta llamada controllers y ahí crear el archivo para hacer las respectivas consultas a la bd (toda tu lógica del proyecto).

Partimos que ya creaste la carpeta Controller y ahí creamos un archivo llamado `ReservoirController.php` (el nombre queda a tu criterio). Estanciamos la conexión a la base de datos y los métodos de tu crude.

```
<?php 
  class ReservoirController extends Connect {
    
    public function __construct(){
      //Ejecutar el codigo de Connect
      parent::__construct();
    }
      
    //Operaciones CRUDE
    public function mostrar(){}
    public function mostrarUno(){}
    public function crear(){}
    public function editar(){}
    public function eliminar
  }
?>
```

Por ultimo el paso 3:

- En modelo deseamos crear un archivo donde tengas las mismas propiedades que tu tabla de la base de datos, ya que de esa manera tu representas en codigo esa tabla (u objeto)

```
<?php
class Reserva {
  public $id;
  public $nombre;
  public $fecha_ingreso;
  //y demas..

//ademas agregamos los setter, getters y el toString
  public function setId($id){}
  public function getId(){}

  public function setNombre($nombre){}
  public function getNombre(){}

  public function setFechIngreso($fecha_ingreso){}
  public function getFechaIngreso(){}

  public toString(){
    return $this->id ." " .$this->nombre ." " .$this->fecha_ingreso;
  }
}

?>
```

Con esta explicación queda mas claro acerca del mvc, espero que esto te pueda ayudar para lo que buscas y necesitas, sino, escribeme y con gusto te hecho la mano.

Comment: Hola @Edgar Gc ,espero que te encuentres bien , como podría comunicarme contigo ?, algún correo ?,si esta la posibilidad de realizar unas consultas

Comment: Hola, feliz año :) Podemos hacerlo aquí en stack overflow o puedes escribirme en twitter (el link esta en mi perfil de stackoverflow).

Comment: hola feliz año igual para ti, te envié un correo , saludos